# Unity HLSL shader shows as pink with no errors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

We are working with an hlsl wireframe shader in Unity 2020.3.8 (two separate shader files, both relatively identical) and the result of the shader is pink in the Unity editor on Mac but shows correctly as wireframe in the Unity editor on PC or when built to APK.

No errors are produced - just pink. I've checked [similar posts](https://forum.unity.com/threads/shader-pink-magenta-when-building-for-windows-but-works-on-mac.1263488/), however none of our `#pragma` lines are exclusive.

What could be the issue?

Shader for front :

```
Shader "Unlit/WireframeQuadFront"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _WireframeFrontColour("Wireframe front colour", color) = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        _WireframeBackColour("Wireframe back colour", color) = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        _WireframeAliasing("Wireframe aliasing", float) = 1.5
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Transparent"}
        LOD 100
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            // Removes the front facing triangles, this enables us to create the wireframe for those behind.
            Cull Front
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma geometry geom
            // make fog work
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            // We add our barycentric variables to the geometry struct.
            struct g2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float3 barycentric : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                // We push the conversion to ClipPos into the geom function as we need 
                // the mesh vertex values for the edge culling.
                //o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.vertex = v.vertex;
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            // This applies the barycentric coordinates to each vertex in a triangle.
            [maxvertexcount(3)]
            void geom(triangle v2f IN[3], inout TriangleStream<g2f> triStream) {
                float edgeLengthX = length(IN[1].vertex - IN[2].vertex);
                float edgeLengthY = length(IN[0].vertex - IN[2].vertex);
                float edgeLengthZ = length(IN[0].vertex - IN[1].vertex);
                float3 modifier = float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                // We're fine using if statments it's a trivial function.
                if ((edgeLengthX > edgeLengthY) && (edgeLengthX > edgeLengthZ)) {
                    modifier = float3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                }
                else if ((edgeLengthY > edgeLengthX) && (edgeLengthY > edgeLengthZ)) {
                    modifier = float3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
                }
                else if ((edgeLengthZ > edgeLengthX) && (edgeLengthZ > edgeLengthY)) {
                    modifier = float3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                }

                g2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN[0].vertex);
                o.barycentric = float3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0) + modifier;
                triStream.Append(o);
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN[1].vertex);
                o.barycentric = float3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0) + modifier;
                triStream.Append(o);
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN[2].vertex);
                o.barycentric = float3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0) + modifier;
                triStream.Append(o);
            }

            fixed4 _WireframeBackColour;
            float _WireframeAliasing;

            fixed4 frag(g2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Calculate the unit width based on triangle size.
                float3 unitWidth = fwidth(i.barycentric);
                // Alias the line a bit.
                float3 aliased = smoothstep(float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), unitWidth * _WireframeAliasing, i.barycentric);
                // Use the coordinate closest to the edge.
                float alpha = 1 - min(aliased.x, min(aliased.y, aliased.z));
                // Set to our backwards facing wireframe colour.
                return fixed4(_WireframeBackColour.r, _WireframeBackColour.g, _WireframeBackColour.b, alpha);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```